# Validation and DDD - kotlin data classes

Tags: validation, kotlin, domain-driven-design

In Java I would do validation when creating constructor in domain object, but when using data class from kotlin I don't know how to make similar validation. I could do that in application service, but I want to stick to domain object and it's logic. It's better to show on example.

```
public class Example {

    private String name;

    Example(String name) {
        validateName(name);
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

In Kotlin I have just a data class is there a way to do it similarly to Java style?

```
data class Example(val name: String)
```

Comment: Interesting write-up on approaches to Value-based classes in Kotlin: https://medium.com/@dev.ahmedmourad73744/value-based-classes-and-error-handling-in-kotlin-3f14727c0565

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get a similar effect by using *[companion factory method](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects)* 
:

```
data class Example private constructor(val name: String) {
    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(name: String): Example {
            //validateName
            return Example(name)
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
val e = Example("name")
e.name //validated
```

Comment: Though constructor is privet, you can still create `Example` with an invalid state by `copy` method of data class. E.g.: ```val ex = Example("validValue")``` and then ```ex.copy("invalidValue")```

Comment: If there is a logic which determinate if name is valid or not it's better to use `ValidatedNameString` class which makes impossible for anybody to use invalid string

Comment: @Teimuraz you won’t be able to do that if ‘name’ is a ‘val’

Comment: @FanaSithole yes you will. The public copy method creates a new instance using the primary constructor of the data class, exposing the private constructor.

Comment: That's a bit of mind fuckery, and the link does no longer mention them. Even though I found an article explaining it, I still think the author makes a good argument for having named factory methods :) https://proandroiddev.com/til-that-you-can-use-the-invoke-operator-on-companion-objects-too-b0d21a870079

Answer (score 57):

You can put your validation code inside an [`initializer block`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors). This will execute regardless of whether the object was instantiated via the primary constructor or via the `copy` method.

```
data class Example(val name: String) {
    init {
        require(name.isNotBlank()) { "Name is blank" }
    }
}
```

A simple example:

```
fun main() {
    println(Example(name = "Alice"))
    println(try { Example(name = "") } catch (e: Exception) { e })
    println(try { Example(name = "Bob").copy(name = "")  } catch (e: Exception) { e })
}
```

Produces:

```
Example(name=Alice)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name is blank
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name is blank
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the interface to hide the data class.
The amount of code will increase slightly, but I think it's more powerful.

```
interface Example {
    val id: String
    val name: String

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(name: String): Example {
            // Validate ...

            return ExampleData(
                id = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                name = name
            )
        }
    }
    
    fun copy(name: String): Example
    
    operator fun component1() : String
    operator fun component2() : String
}

private data class ExampleData(override val id: String, override val name: String): Example {
    override fun copy(name: String): Example = Example(name)
}
```